# Access the html inside an active Modal

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

I am trying to check in Capybara, for the content displayed inside the Modal:

```
# expect(page).to have_content 'Lock Admin?'
```

But, this is returning false, even though the text is present in the modal, as shown below..
I am using the default driver "RackTest" for the purpose, with `:js => true` in my scenario.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have specified :js => true then you are not (with Capybaras default setup) using the rack-test driver, you would be using whatever driver Capybara.javascript_driver is set to, by default that would be selenium and it would open an instance of firefox when running the test.

From your picture that doesn't look like a system modal, so I'm assuming it's a just an html modal - bootstrap/etc.  In that case your expectation should work, although to check that the text is in a modal it would be more correct to do something like

```
expect(page).to have_css('.modalBox', text: 'Lock Admin?')
```

where the first parameter is whatever css selector would find the modal.  If something like that isn't working for you, you'll need to post the html for your modal, and the whole test thats failing.